# RetroFit 2: Object is not being formed correctly after sending to server

Tags: android, retrofit2

This is my interface that I have:

```
public interface DistributionServerAPI {
    @Headers("Content-type: application/json")
    @POST("device/add")
    Call<DeviceModel> createDevice(@Body ArrayList<DeviceModel> deviceArray);
}
```

In my Device.java file:

```
public class Device extends Fragment {
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (numberOfDevices > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDevices; i++) {
                    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)rootView.findViewById(i);
                    for (int index = 1; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); index++) {
                        DeviceModel device = new DeviceModel();
                        switch (index) {
                            case 1:
                                device.setName(deviceName);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                device.setColor(deviceColor);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    deviceModelArrayList.add(device);
                }

                Call<DeviceModel> deviceModel = api.createDevice(deviceModelArrayList);

                deviceModel.enqueue(new Callback<DeviceModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<DeviceModel> call, Response<DeviceModel> response) {
                        Log.d("POSTING DEVICE", "DEVICE SAVE WAS SUCCESS");     
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<DeviceModel> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("POSTING DEVICE", "DEVICE SAVE WAS FAILURE"); 
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In the above `Device.java` is where I create my `ArrayList` (the `deviceModelArrayList` variable) which has Device objects (`DeviceModel`) that contain 2 properties the name and the color.

The ArrayList is being sent to the server but for some reason the object isn't being formed correctly. In the switch statement in my for loop I set the `name` and `color` of the device and I add it to the `ArrayList`.

I have 4 devices which is add to the `ArrayList` but when I print out the object on the server side I only have 2 device objects and the `color` property is not even present in any of those objects.

It looks like this:

```
[{"name": "device1"}, {"name": "device2"}]
```

There is no color property and there is only 2 devices instead of 4. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? Is it ok to use the switch inside of the for loop. Like does the break statement break out of the switch only or the inner for loop?

Comment: Your code contains error DeviceModel device = new DeviceModel(); should be outside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one, you should use tag instead of id if you want to getting your view like that. and the second one as you can see from your code

```
for (int index = 1; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); index++) {
    DeviceModel device = new DeviceModel();
    switch (index) {
        case 1:
            device.setName(deviceName);
            break;
        case 2:
            device.setColor(deviceColor);
            break;
    }
}
```

With this logic, your device model will never have both name and color, because you are creating a new object inside the loop where you also setting the properties.

Your code should look like this if you want to retain one DeviceModel for every ViewGroup

```
         for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDevices; i++) {
                ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)rootView.findViewById(i);
                DeviceModel device = new DeviceModel();
                for (int index = 1; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); index++) {
                    switch (index) {
                        case 1:
                            device.setName(deviceName);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            device.setColor(deviceColor);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                deviceModelArrayList.add(device);
            }
```

This way, you will have one DeviceModel for every ViewGroup instead one for every ViewGroupChild